# Stop DIV from overlapping other DIVs (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want only 3 DIVs on top of each other. It's not a lot of code, and when I do it plainly without any content, it stacks properly. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but here goes the code. I want one more DIV underneath the middle content DIV. This is used for a bottom information bar. I understand `z-index` is more used for layers, and would not be beneficial to my knowledge.

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mt. Rose, City of Refuge MEdia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="storage/mainsite/styles/default_button.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="storage/mainsite/styles/default_font.css"
          type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="storage/mainsite/styles/default_div.css"
          type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center;">
<br>

<div class="maindefault" style="display: block;"><!--Banner insert -->
    <img src="storage/mainsite/bannerfinalfeathered.png" alt=""><a
        class="button"
        href="http://output93.rssinclude.com/output?type=iframe&amp;id=456111&amp;hash=c334e7f73918b535f66271d019d52a83"
        title="Home" target="content"><span>Home</span></a> <a class="button"
                                                               title="About Us"
                                                               href="http://mtrosecogic.org/mtrose1/about"><span>About</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="index.html" title="Mt. Rose Public Calendar"><span>Calendar</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="/flash_newpage.html" title="Live Video Feed"><span>Live
Feed</span></a> <a class="button" target="content" href="access.html"
                   title="Restricted"><span>Access</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="index.html"
       title="Mt. Rose Virtual Learning Environment"><span>Education</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="/flash_newpage.html"
       title="City of Refuge Online Webstore!"><span>Store</span></a>
    <a class="button" target="content" href="/interactive.html"
       title="Interactive Media Gallery"><span><font face="Juice">Interactive</font></span></a>
</div>
<br>

<div class="maindefault">
    <iframe
        style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; width: 416px; height: 800px; float: left;"
        float="" marginheight="0" src="flash_newpage.html" id="flashframe"
        name="flashframe" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <iframe
        style="overflow: auto; margin-top: 6em; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 600px; width: 400px; float: right; text-align: center;"
        id="content" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
        src="http://output93.rssinclude.com/output?type=iframe&amp;id=456111&amp;hash=c334e7f73918b535f66271d019d52a83"
        name="content" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS for div (It's a linked Stylesheet):

```
.maindefault {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 817px;
    font-family: "High Tower Text",Georgia,Serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, I am using Kompozer 8.3 if that helps. ThankYOU

EDIT:: I'm not familiar with JS Fiddler, but the link is mtrosemedia.tk. What happens is when I add another `.maindefault div` underneath the last `</div>`, my new DIV is snug at the top of the second DIV. I need the new DIV to be snug against the bottom of the second DIV. Then, when I add content, it shows on top of my flash and my RSS feed. I want to improve the feed listing as well, but I'll make that another question.

Comment: It would help if you would post a link to a working site or a jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the divs overlap when you put content inside?

Try floating the .maindefault left.  When the content is added, the next div should align nice and snug against the top of the one above it.

Comment: EDIT:: I'm not familiar with JS Fiddler, but the link is mtrosemedia.tk. What happens is when I add another .maindefault div underneath the last , my new DIV is snug at the top of the second DIV. I need the new DIV to be snug against the bottom of the second DIV. Then, when I add content, it shows on top of my flash and my RSS feed. I want to improve the feed listing as well, but I'll make that another question.